# Remove all style, scripts, and html tags from an html page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cleanme(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # create a new bs4 object from the html data loaded
    for script in soup(["script"]): 
        script.extract()
    text = soup.get_text()
    return text
testhtml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<head>\n<title>THIS IS AN EXAMPLE </title><style>.call {font-family:Arial;}</style><script>getit</script><body>I need this text captured<h1>And this</h1></body>"

cleaned = cleanme(testhtml)
print (cleaned)
```

This is working to remove the script

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like you almost have it. You need to also remove the html tags and css styling code. Here is my solution (I updated the function):

```
def cleanMe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") # create a new bs4 object from the html data loaded
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # remove all javascript and stylesheet code
        script.extract()
    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()
    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    return text
```

Comment: @Anu this works for me: `relist = re.split("window.fbAsyncInit+", texttotest)
print(relist[0])` you can see that the regex split works fine, for the texttotest variable I used your example text in full.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`decompose`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to completely remove the tags from the document and [`stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) generator to retrieve the tag content.

```
def clean_me(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for s in soup(['script', 'style']):
        s.decompose()
    return ' '.join(soup.stripped_strings)
```

---

```
>>> clean_me(testhtml) 
'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE I need this text captured And this'
```

Answer (score 6):

Removing specified tags and comments in a clean manner. Thanks to [Kim Hyesung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7016945/kim-hyesung) for [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529848/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-write-the-output-to-html-file).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

def cleanMe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")    
    [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('script')]
    [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('style')]
    [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('meta')]
    [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('noscript')]
    [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))]
    return soup
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) instead:

```
# Requirements: pip install lxml

import lxml.html.clean


def cleanme(content):
    cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(
        allow_tags=[''],
        remove_unknown_tags=False,
        style=True,
    )
    html = lxml.html.document_fromstring(content)
    html_clean = cleaner.clean_html(html)
    return html_clean.text_content().strip()

testhtml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<head>\n<title>THIS IS AN EXAMPLE </title><style>.call {font-family:Arial;}</style><script>getit</script><body>I need this text captured<h1>And this</h1></body>"
cleaned = cleanme(testhtml)
print (cleaned)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick and dirty solution you ca use:

```
re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', value)
```

To make an equivalent of [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) in php.
Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation in addition to [styvane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565597/15164646) answer. If you want to extract a lot of text, check out [`selectolax`](https://github.com/rushter/selectolax), it's much faster than `lxml`

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Extract-plain-text-from-HTML):

```py
def clean_me(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    body = soup.body
    if body is None:
        return None

    # removing everything besides text
    for tag in body.select('script'):
        tag.decompose()
    for tag in body.select('style'):
        tag.decompose()

    plain_text = body.get_text(separator='\n').strip()
    print(plain_text)

clean_me()
```