# How to write the output to html file with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I modified an html file by removing some of the tags using `beautifulsoup`. Now I want to write the results back in a html file.
My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('1.html'),"html.parser")

[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('script')]
[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('style')]
[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('meta')]
[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('noscript')]
[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))]
html =soup.contents
for i in html:
    print i

html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open("output1.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

Since I used `soup.prettify`, it generates html like this:

```
<p>
    <strong>
     BATAM.TRIBUNNEWS.COM, BINTAN
    </strong>
    - Tradisi pedang pora mewarnai serah terima jabatan pejabat di
    <a href="http://batam.tribunnews.com/tag/polres/" title="Polres">
     Polres
    </a>
    <a href="http://batam.tribunnews.com/tag/bintan/" title="Bintan">
     Bintan
    </a>
    , Senin (3/10/2016).
</p>
```

I want to get the result like `print i` does:

```
<p><strong>BATAM.TRIBUNNEWS.COM, BINTAN</strong> - Tradisi pedang pora mewarnai serah terima jabatan pejabat di <a href="http://batam.tribunnews.com/tag/polres/" title="Polres">Polres</a> <a href="http://batam.tribunnews.com/tag/bintan/" title="Bintan">Bintan</a>, Senin (3/10/2016).</p>
<p>Empat perwira baru Senin itu diminta cepat bekerja. Tumpukan pekerjaan rumah sudah menanti di meja masing masing.</p>
```

How can I get a result the same as `print i` (ie. so the tag and its content appear on the same line)? Thanks.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Just *convert the `soup` instance to string* and write:

```
with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: If you get encoding issues use this `with open("output1.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:`

Answer (score 44):

For Python 3, `unicode` was renamed to `str`, but I did have to pass in the encoding argument to opening the file to avoid an `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
with open("output1.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 10):

Use unicode to be safe:

```
with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(unicode(soup))
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, as mentioned by @andytham, you can only use `unicode()` for Python 2; use `str()` instead for Python 3