# How to output soup to .html using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a weblink and I want to save the whole webpage to a local file in format `.html`. I want to directly output soup to an `html` file locally for uploading a copy to S3-AWS ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_name = "https://<weblink>/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_name,"html.parser")
```

Now, I am just wondering, like `.txt` can we output soup to `.html as well`. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529848/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-write-the-output-to-html-file)?

Answer (score -2):

You imported requests but never actually used it. You need to GET the actual site

```
r=requests.get(url_name)
```

Then you can pass that to BS

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

Comment: @yan `r.txt` is the response content, if that's what you mean. Anyway an html file is a text file basically, so all you have to do is save your file as .html