# How can I specifically remove a tag with a class using re.sub

Tags: python, html

I want to filter out p tag with a class from the HTML below, while not affecting any other p tags following it.

```
<article data-article-content>
    <div class="abc">
       <p class="ghf">Some Text</p>
       <p>Some other Text</p>
       <p>A different Text</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

What I am using:

```
def myFunction(result):
    result = re.sub(r'<article data-article-content><div class="abc"><p class="ghf">.*?</p><\/article>',' ',result)
    return result
```

I will call this function and printing that out should omit 'Some Text'.
I am a beginner in regex. Please help with suggestions

Expected Output:

Some other Text
A different Text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't use regex to parse HTML. It's a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8967612). But [why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/8967612) Here are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724992/8967612) of problems you might run into. Use an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11709079/8967612) instead.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the given HTML. Maybe you can explain the use-case or context a bit more, so we can find a better solution than regex. Because regex might restrict your solution tremendously.

Comment: There is no `</p><\/article>` so of course the regex doesn't match. Replacing through the end of `</article>` would obviously replace all the `<p>` nodes, not just the first one. Could you please [edit] to clarify what the expected result should be?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am fetching the main body from websites. And I want to avoid scraping unwanted texts from it. I am trying BeautifulSoup now. I will update the question with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). It's a fantastic HTML parser and it has a very intuitive API. I've used it hundreds of times for large and small projects.

```py
html = '''
<article data-article-content>
    <div class="abc">
       <p class="ghf">Some Text</p>
       <p>Some other Text</p>
       <p>A different Text</p>
    </div>
</article>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

ps = soup.find_all('p')

p_with_class = [p for p in ps if p.get('class') is not None][0]

print(p_with_class)
# <p class="ghf">Some Text</p>

# Remove it.
p_with_class.decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <article data-article-content="">
   <div class="abc">
    <p>
     Some other Text
    </p>
    <p>
     A different Text
    </p>
   </div>
  </article>
 </body>
</html>
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529848).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I have started using BeautifulSoup. I will get back at this once I reach some point.

Answer (score 0):

With *BeautifulSoup* you could transform the given HTML so that

- any `<p>` tag with class `ghf` is removed

#### Input

```html
<article data-article-content>
    <div class="abc">
       <p class="ghf">Some Text</p>
       <p>Some other Text</p>
       <p>A different Text</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

#### Expected Output

```html
<article data-article-content="">
<div class="abc">

<p>Some other Text</p>
<p>A different Text</p>
</div>
</article>
```

#### With BeautifulSoup

Here using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), version 4, also known by acronym *bs4*.

Install using `pip`:

> pip install beautifulsoup4

Then parse, find, modify and print:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<article data-article-content>
    <div class="abc">
       <p class="ghf">Some Text</p>
       <p>Some other Text</p>
       <p>A different Text</p>
    </div>
</article>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser') # parses HTML using python's internal HTML-parser

found_paragraphs = soup.find("p", {"class": "ghf"}) # find your element
found_paragraphs.extract() # removes and leaves an empty line

print(soup) # unfortunately indentation is lost
```

You could use [`prettify()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=prettify) on `soup` to get some indentation back.

#### See also

The functions used are explained in detail in related questions & answers:

- [Exclude unwanted tag on Beautifulsoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760441/exclude-unwanted-tag-on-beautifulsoup-python)
- [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)
- [BeautifulSoup innerhtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112922/beautifulsoup-innerhtml#18602241)
- [Don't put html, head and body tags automatically, beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822188/dont-put-html-head-and-body-tags-automatically-beautifulsoup)