# Python - remove markup tags and read html from the file?

Tags: python, html, text, information-retrieval, data-extraction

I have a file called BBC_news_home.html  I need to remove all markup tags so all Im left with is just some text. So far I got:

```
def clean_html(html):
    cleaned = ''

line = html

pattern = r'(<.*?>)'

result = re.findall(pattern, line, re.S)

if result:
    f = codecs.open("BBC_news_home.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
    print(f.read())
else:
    print('Not cleaned.')
return cleaned
```

I have checked with regex101.com that the pattern is correct Im just not sure how to print the output to check if markup tags are gone?

Comment: You probably want to look into [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), more specifically [.get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be using BeautifulSoup for this. Do `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4` or `pip install BeautifulSoup4` depending on the version of python you need. I already posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565420/1215344). For completeness sake:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cleanme(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # create a new bs4 object from the html data loaded
    for script in soup(["script"]): 
        script.extract()
    text = soup.get_text()
    return text
testhtml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<head>\n<title>THIS IS AN EXAMPLE </title><style>.call {font-family:Arial;}</style><script>getit</script><body>I need this text captured<h1>And this</h1></body>"

cleaned = cleanme(testhtml)
print (cleaned)
```

And the output will be merely `I need this text captured And this` for the result.