# How to extract pure text from html without any additional (SCRIPT, STYLE, CSS, XML, HTML etc. tags) using python

Tags: html

I am working with fetching plain text from the HTML file. The HTML file is pure HTML data directly copy-paste from the website (no encoding issues). HTML is a bit complex because it's mixed with a lot of comments

I have tried the beautiful soup get_text(), find_all(), all the parsers of BS4. I also tried the html2text.

```
def clean_html(data):
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features = "lxml", from_encoding = 'utf8')
# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
script.extract()  # rip it out
text = soup.get_text()  # get text
return text
```

this fetches all the useless tags, design elements, scripts with text. I am not able to parse it because I have more than 50k HTML's and every time format is different with different tags.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND AN ANSWER FOR MY ABOVE QUESTION,

cleanMe() FROM

REF: [Remove all style, scripts, and html tags from an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565404/remove-all-style-scripts-and-html-tags-from-an-html-page)

ANSWER BY @jamescampbell

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`decompose()` `bs4` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).

If you need to extract plain text from hundreds of HTMLs, have a look at [selectolax](https://github.com/rushter/selectolax) which is **really** fast, faster than `lxml`.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/CrookedAcidicLivecd#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'User-agent':
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "lasagna recipe",
  "hl": "en"
}

def get_plain_text():

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text, 'lxml')

    body = soup.body
    if body is None:
        return None

    for tag in body.select('script'):
        tag.decompose()
    for tag in body.select('style'):
        tag.decompose()

    text = body.get_text(separator='\n').strip()
    print(text)

get_plain_text()
```